# How to change font size with replacement text

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

i have this code :

```
        For Each footr In word_fichier.Sections(1).Headers
            With footr.Range.Find
                .Text = MaFeuille.Cells(j, 1)
                .Replacement.Text = MaFeuille.Cells(j, 2)
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next footr
    Next j
```

And i want that the replacement text have another font size. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use this easy adapted way:

```
        For Each footr In word_fichier.Sections(1).Headers
            With footr.Range.Find
                .Text = MaFeuille.Cells(j, 1)
                .Replacement.Text = MaFeuille.Cells(j, 2)
                .Replacement.Font.Size = 24 'use here the size you need...
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next footr
```